# React setState not updating array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I'm having a problem with setState not updating my todoItems array. I read through the other posts here that have dealt with the same issue. In my addTodoItem() I changed this.setState to a function and I'm now using the spread operator, A new item is being generated in the array. This is what logs:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {id: "1", item: "Learn React."}1: {id: 
"2", item: "Do Yoga."}2: {id: "3", item: "Be kind."}3: {id: "4", 
item: "Have Fun"}length: 4__proto__: Array(0)
App.js:36 todo: Have Fun
```

But it doesn't actually update the array. When I refresh it reverts to the original state. From what I read I think I'm having the state updating async issue. What am I missing?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      value: '',
      listItemValue: props.value || '',
      todoItems:  [
        {id: _.uniqueId(), item: 'Learn React.'},
        {id: _.uniqueId(), item: 'Do Yoga.'},
        {id: _.uniqueId(), item: 'Be kind.'}
      ]
    };

    this.addTodoItem = this.addTodoItem.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    let value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      value: this.state.value,
      listItemValue: value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      value: '',
      listItemValue: ''
    });
  }

  addTodoItem = () => {
    let todoItems = this.state.todoItems.slice();
    todoItems.push({
      id: _.uniqueId(),
      item: this.state.listItemValue
    });
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      todoItems: [
        ...prevState.todoItems,
        {
          id: _.uniqueId(),
          item: this.state.listItemValue
        }
      ]
    }))
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Todo List</h1>
        <TodoListForm name="todo"
                      onClick={()=>this.addTodoItem()}
                      onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }
                      handleChange={ this.handleChange }
                      value={ this.state.listItemValue } />
        <TodoList todoItems={ this.state.todoItems }/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "When I refresh". Like literally refreshing the browser?

Comment: I mean it always reverts back to the original state of the array. The new item is never really added into the array.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "revert back". Do you mean the item is added, but after refreshing the page it goes back to the original state?

Comment: @TYPOI On `addTodoItem` you are updating your state asynchronously, while on `handleChange` the state is being updated synchronously. I'm not sure, but there may some kind of race condition... and I would try to make all state updates in asynchronous way, passing a function as an argument of `setState`.

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: @dhilt state updates are always asynchronous and they will be batched. This is why using the current state or props to update the state require to pass a function to `setState()` that takes the next state and the next props as arguments and returns the next state from that.

Comment: You can get rid of those `bind` statements in the constructor if you declare the class methods as arrows instead: `handleSubmit = (event) => {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React "state" does not do what you think it does. It's not a persistent data source like a database or `localStorage`. Items in state, like any other variable in JavaScript, only exist for the lifetime of a single load. The moment you refresh a web page, every variable is wiped and reinitialized as if it were the first time you landed on the page.

If you want to persist state, you need to use something that persists across refreshes, sessions etc.

If you don't have a server, or don't need one, you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or other browser storage systems, however those are not good for long term persistence. At some point, depending on what you're building, you will need to use a server that connects to a database.

Comment: Ok, lightbulb moment. LOL Thank you @azium